# Synergy - Keyboard not working on Windows with OSX Server

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard, synergy

I'm using a standard Apple Keyboard and an HP mouse. Both are USB. I start the server on the Mac, and then the client. The mouse works correctly on the windows machine, but when I try to type, nothing appears.

Here's my config:

```
section: screens
    us147137.local:
    windows:  
end
section: links
    us147137.local:
        left = windows
    windows:
        right = us147137.local
end
```

I gave the windows box a screen name of **windows** for some reason, but that shouldn't cause the problem anyway, right?

You think it's just because of the Apple keyboard?

Thanks!

**EDIT: Downgrade to the version below latest and it works!**

Comment: What version of Synergy are you using?  I used a self-compiled version of the Mac server for 2 years with one to two Windows clients without issue.  Used an Apple Alu keyboard the entire time. So its not the Apple keyboard.

Comment: Latest version for both client/server.

Comment: @dmackerman it would help, if you provide the version info of the patch you got working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this exact same problem, only with a Linux client and my OSX server.  I rolled back to the synergy version 1.3.6 and had to run the server as root.  However, I never got copy and paste to work this way.

You should also contribute to this bug report:
http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/57

Answer (score 1):

I think this is [issue 47](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=47)

Comment: Possibly. How do I install these patches?

Comment: One of the solutions noted there is to use SynergyKM on MacOS - this worked fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of Mac as server and Linux as client. Mouse worked and keyboard did not. After I "sudo synergys" to start the server as root, keyboard starts to work.